# What is a duality argument?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators, dual-spaces

I believe this is probably a question that can have a wide variety of answers, but i believe i'm still interested. The thing is, i have been in a couple pde talks, and i saw that in both of these talks they made some estimates calculus refering to duality arguments, and i really don't know what this duality arguments are.

I know that it depends on some cases i can have different duality arguments, but can u give me some examples of some duality arguments, or how this came up on theory.

In summary i would like to have as much information i can about this topic since i really dont know what those duality arguments are, so references would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Duplicate in Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100905/duality-argument-in-pde)